# Find only circular links in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to Neo4j and have been playing with an idea about people moving houses, in order to learn more about cypher. This is what I have currently

Each `Person` [:OWNS] a `House`

Each `House` [:ISIN] a `Street`

A `Person` [:WANTS] (to live in) a `Street`

The aim is to find a complete 'chain'

If I run

`MATCH (s:Street)<-[:WANTS]-(p:Person)-[:OWNS]->(h:House) RETURN s,h,p`

This returns me the complete chain linking right back to the person.
What I'm trying to do is only return complete chains and not broken ones.

I've also tried

`MATCH (s:Street)<-[:WANTS]-(p:Person)-[:OWNS]->(h:House)-[:ISIN]->(s) RETURN s,h,p`

but this never returns results. Any thoughts?

UPDATE

I got the last query returning results by doing this
`MATCH (s:Street)<-[:WANTS]-(p:Person)-[:OWNS]->(h:House)-[:ISIN]->(s1: Street) RETURN s,h,p`

But am not sure if this is what I want.

I just want to return circular results so I can see complete house moving chains. Ultimately​ based on one person so I'll need to put a WHERE in there.

I will try move queries tomorrow with a larger dataset

Comment: What about the sample data and the desired result?

Comment: Desired result was in there 'What I'm trying to do is only return complete chains and not broken ones.' How would you like the data set?

Comment: "never returns results" !?
It may be that such circular reference actually do not exists in database?

Answer (score 0):

MATCH won't repeat a node in a chain, aka a single match can't match the same node in two variables. But you can just break out the last chain to a where clause

```
MATCH (s:Street)<-[:WANTS]-(p:Person)-[:OWNS]->(h:House)
WHERE (h)-[:ISIN]->(s) 
RETURN s,h,p
```